# Groovy jenkins pipeline @NonCPSreturn not expected results

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

In my code I have a method that parse log file and return list of results. Without NonCPS it works perfect and return correct values. This method is called from pipeline stages and I got java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.regex.Matcher that's why I put @NonCPS annotation. Exception is not thrown anymore but log_parser method doesnt work well. Now it always return whole file - even if remove return result_list. The result of calling this method is always file.

```
    @NonCPS
    def log_parser(String filename){
    def result_list = []
    def match_f, match_s
    def lines = readFile(filename).readLines()

    for( line in lines ) {
        match_f = (line =~ /(?<=Failures: )[^ ]+/ )
        match_s = (line =~ /(?<=Skips: )[^ ]+/ )

        if( match_f ) {
            result_list[1] = (match_f[0]).replace(",", "") }
        if( match_s ) {
            result_list[2] = (match_s[0]).replace(",", "") }
    }
    return result_list
    }
```

Comment: could you provide log sample and expected result?

Comment: file with some logs and containing line "Total tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 0" and what I want is to pull Failures and Skips so I expect list = [0, 0]. As I said this method works fine, the problem is java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.regex.Matcher or when @NonCPS is on fact that method return whole file insted of the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because pipeline will serialize all variables (includes local variable inside function) as default behaviour, but `java.util.regex.Matcher` is not serializable, that's why you get the error.

**Option 1)** release not serializable variable immediately once you complete using it.

```
def log_parser(String filename){
    def result_list = []
    def match_f, match_s
    def lines = readFile(filename).readLines()

    for( line in lines ) {
        match_f = (line =~ /(?<=Failures: )[^ ]+/ )
        match_s = (line =~ /(?<=Skips: )[^ ]+/ )

        if( match_f ) {
            result_list[1] = (match_f[0]).replace(",", "")
            match_f = null
        }
        if( match_s ) {
            result_list[2] = (match_s[0]).replace(",", "")
            match_s = null 
        }
    }
    return result_list
}
```

**Option 2)** move not serializable variables into function with annotation: `@NonCPS`, **inside @NonCPS function, we can't call any other pipeline step**, therefor you should move `readFile` out of `log_pareser()`

```
log_parser(readFile(<log file path>))

@NonCPS
def log_parser(String fileContent){
    def result_list = []
    def match_f, match_s
    def lines = fileContent.readLines()

    for( line in lines ) {
        match_f = (line =~ /(?<=Failures: )[^ ]+/ )
        match_s = (line =~ /(?<=Skips: )[^ ]+/ )

        if( match_f ) {
            result_list[1] = (match_f[0]).replace(",", "") }
        if( match_s ) {
            result_list[2] = (match_s[0]).replace(",", "") }
    }
    return result_list
}
```

Comment: I used Option 2 and it works perfectly! I'm extremely grateful. Thank you :)

Comment: DUUUUUDE FKIN A !!! The IMPORTANT PART OF YOUR ANSWER IS BOLD (i would say GOLD also) => `inside @NonCPS function, we can't call any other pipeline step, therefor you should move readFile out of log_pareser`