# Not serializable error for jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to trigger my email promotion job from my pipeline which extracts the repo name from `Jenkins` messages. But not able to resolve the `SerializableException` error for this block. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
post{
        success{
            script{
                @NonCPS
                //upstream_job_name = null
                def manager = manager.getLogMatcher('.*Obtained Jenkinsfile from git (.*)$')
                if(manager.matches()){
                    def gitMsg=manager.group(1)
                    gitrepo = "${gitMsg}"
                    echo gitrepo
                    def upstream_job_name = gitrepo.split("/")[4].replace(".git", "")
                    println upstream_job_name

                }
                build job: 'job-approval' , parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'upstream_job_name', value: upstream_job_name]]


            }
        }
    }
```

Below is the error messages i am receiving :

[Pipeline] // script
Error when executing success post condition:

> java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.regex.Matcher
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:926)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)

Comment: Think you have to put that into a function and annotate that with `@NonCPS`

Comment: Agreed. I do not believe you can arbitrarily annotate inside the declarative DSL and outside a method like that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but unfortunately i am not able to resolve it and started getting lot of errors. I tried creating mail.groovy function where it performs the regex operations to find the reponame. Any example will really helpful. BTW i was following @StephenKing's previous messages on declarative pipeline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to release `manager` immediately after using. More detail can find in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55684174/groovy-jenkins-pipeline-noncpsreturn-not-expected-results/55685723#55685723)

```
script{

    //upstream_job_name = null
    def manager = manager.getLogMatcher('.*Obtained Jenkinsfile from git (.*)$')
    if(manager.matches()){
        def gitMsg=manager.group(1)
        gitrepo = "${gitMsg}"
        echo gitrepo
        def upstream_job_name = gitrepo.split("/")[4].replace(".git", "")
        println upstream_job_name      
    }
    manager = null

    build job: 'job-approval' , 
        parameters: [
            [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'upstream_job_name', value: upstream_job_name]
        ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yong. It worked. And the link you shared really helped my understanding. Only change i did is uncommented the second line and included def
{def upstream_job_name = ""}

And 8th line remove the "def"
{upstream_job_name = gitrepo.split("/")[4].replace(".git", "")}

Thanks a lot, i was able to successfully run both jobs.